# Delete has_and_belongs_to_many table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database structure like this:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

And in my controller I say

```
Book.all.each do |b|
   b.destroy!
end
```

And I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ?):
```

I have tried one of SO answers like this

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors, dependent :nullify
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, dependent :nulligy
end
```

But no joy...
I'm new to rails. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Changing dependent to :destroy is the correct answer. You might also like to know that you could replace your delete block with Book.destroy_all

Comment: Could you show your migration, please?

Comment: What you originally wrote should have worked.

Comment: @Schwern, you are right. The problem was with the migration.

Answer (score 2):

it should be `dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Does `has_and_belongs_to_many` take the dependent option?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> What you originally wrote should have worked

This is correct. I just realized that I had forgotten to create a join table between Author and Book models, and all that problem was I think because of that. So, I created the join table and the problem solved. Actually I think `dependent` has no effect at all on M2M relations.